# binding data to many textboxes with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i have a data binding which is seperated by semicolons,ef (1;3;4;3;) how would i seperate them so it displays each number in a seperate textbox? 
The user also needs to be able to use the add function (allready implemented) so that when data is added back into the textboxes they are stored in sql back with the semicolon delimeter.

```
    {

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", sudokuDataSet, "puzzle.puzzle"));
        textBox2?
        textBox3?

    }
```

Comment: Could you show a little bit more code, and explain where your "semicolons separated" binding is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step.

If you need to show comma delimited numbers into textbox.
You have to store the number in string and then use string.split(,) it will split the numbers and return it to you in array.Now you have each number in seperate array position.You now place that numbers into the textbox by the position of array.

Second step

If you need to get text from more than one textboxes to database by seperated them with a delimeter.You have to create a string and then add textboxes like e.g

`String str = textbox1.Text;

str = str + ',' + textbox2.text;

str = str + ',' + textbox3.text;`

and continue.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you store some numbers in database separated by ";" like 1;2;3;5;7 
if this is your problem then get that in a string and use **string.Split()** and pass separating character to this method  in your case ";" . return an string array. Get values from array and apply to text boxes.
for more info visit [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)